# jQuery Mobile basics

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to learn how to program with jQuery Mobile and I cannot understand why this code doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Start of first page -->
 <div data-role="page" id="First">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>First</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>First Page</p>
    <p>View page called <a href="#Second" data-role="button">Second</a></p>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
 </div><!-- /page -->

 <!-- Start of second page -->
 <div data-role="page" id="Second">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Second</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

 <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Second Page</p>
    <p><a href="#First">Back to First</a></p>
 </div><!-- /content -->

 <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
 </div><!-- /footer -->
 </div><!-- /page -->
 </body>
```

Thank you very much for helping!
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

Comment: what does code doesn't work mean?

Comment: Define "Doesn't work".

Comment: The whole code should represent two pages, and when you click on the "view page called Second" should show the second page and the same thing should happen for the second page.

Comment: For what I Understood with jQuery I can put the code of two or more different pages in the same html file and visualize them one by one hiding the others.

Comment: @EYN It works fine for me using your markup: http://jsfiddle.net/2grdmnqv/ are you sure the path to jQuery Mobile is correct?

Comment: Mh, what do you mean with "path to jQuery Mobile"? I am really a beginner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markup you have posted works fine using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2grdmnqv/).

The only difference between the example you have posted and the one I have created on JSFiddle (apart from the missing closing HTML tag) is the path references to the external libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

Replace your script and stylesheet references with the block above and see if it works. These libraries are hosted on Google's Content Delivery Network (CDN). If this works, the paths to your local versions of these files are wrong and you will need to correct them.

Here is a page explaining about file paths:

http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/